# after restart all media are gone from gallery

Tags: sd-card

(Im not an english user so ignore mistakes)
I have an old gts5360 phone and I add new media to sdcard like photo,video,music,etc. all of this media after restart are gone and not showed up in gallery, but the files still are in sd card.
I think if I run chkdsk solve problem but My phones usb mini socket is damaged so I cant connect it to computer.
any ideas?

Comment: Do the files show up in your file manager?

Comment: yes they are in file manager but do not show up in gallery until I rename them. but even with renaming its still gone after restart

Comment: Try using a different gallery app. There's one called quickpic it's pretty good

Comment: @ABochur quickpic *was* very good before it was sold (I don't trust any app by CM). // The issue here seems to be a problem with the [media scanner](/tags/media-scanner/info) not working correctly. Not a solution, but a possible work-around: try if you can trigger a rescan whenever the media "disappeared" (follow the link for some instructions). Of course you could also use an [alternative gallery app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_galleries) that doesn't use the media library but accesses the media directly. But I'm not sure which to recommend that does this.

Comment: What if your media files are being hidden by, say, a malware that add `.nomedia` file in every folder, especially where media files are stored? What you'll need is identifying the malware then removing it should solvedthe problem. BTW, do you still play music?